# Joomla disable SSL for administrator login

Tags: ssl, joomla, https, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla `3.3.0` installation running on a webserver without any `SSL` configuration or a cert. When I try to log in in the administrator area under `/administrator`, I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` after some seconds of loading because I get redirect to `https://`.

The `config` file contains the following statement:

```
public $force_ssl = '0';
```

Is there any other setting i have to turn off to fully disable `SSL`?

Edit: The form of the login page is pointing at a `HTTPS` url:

```
<form action="https://www.domain.com/administrator/index.php" method="post" id="form-login" class="form-inline">
```

Following extensions are installed:

[image: Installed extensions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 places you will need to check:

- Check your .htaccess file - an entry forcing SSL might be there
- If you have any security extensions, try disabling them from phpMyAdmin
- Check with your host if they are forcing SSL on the "administrator" folder at the server level (this is a remote possibility, but it could happen).
- Go to "Extensions" -> "Modules" and then, on the left, filter as "Administrator" (change from "Site" to "Administrator"), and then search for "Login", and then click on the "Login" module, and then change "Encrypt Login Form" to "No", and then click on "Save".

Comment: I've updated the question. The form submit url already contains a `HTTPS` url, so this shouldn't be caused by `htaccess` or a server level setting - I'm I right?

Comment: If you go to http://www.[yoursite].com/administrator are you automatically redirected to https? (If yes, then most likely this is in the .htaccess file). In any case, you should also check the template file for the login module (located under your 'administrator/templates/template_name/modules/mod_login' folder) and see if the https is hardcoded there.

Comment: Nope - the redirect happens after I click the login button.

Comment: There is no modules folder in any of the available template folders (hathor, isis, system).

Comment: I have updated my answer - I'm sure that the last point in the list is your solution (make sure your clear your Joomla cache after making the change).